# Invalid Arabic characters With Utf-8 charset Retrived with http.get Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Hi i'm trying to [Fetch data from the internet](https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/fetch-data/) in `flutter` and as long as all characters in `response.body` are English everything is fine but i get these results with `persian/arabic` characters.

Link to page i'm testing this with:
http://mobagym.com/media/mobagym-app-info/farsi.html
(I've also tested it with other urls and my api got the same results)

This is my code(I've also tried showing the result in a `Text Widget`):

```
static Future<String> loadFarsi() async{
    final response = await http.get("http://mobagym.com/media/mobagym-app-info/farsi.html",headers:{"charset":"utf-8","Accept-Charset":"utf-8"});
    print(response.body);
    return response.body;
  }
```

I've tried Remove the headers and still no luck.

```
final response = await http.get("http://mobagym.com/media/mobagym-app-info/farsi.html");
```

This is my log from android studio:

```
Performing hot reload...
Reloaded 7 of 507 libraries in 1,333ms.
I/flutter (23060): <html>
I/flutter (23060):     <head>
I/flutter (23060):         <meta charset="utf-8"/>
I/flutter (23060):     </head>
I/flutter (23060):     <body>Ø³ÙØ§Ù  Ø³ÙØ§Ù ÙØ±Ù Ø§ÛÙ¾Ø³ÙÙ</body>
I/flutter (23060): </html>
```

This part is wrong:
**Ø³ÙØ§Ù  Ø³ÙØ§Ù ÙØ±Ù Ø§ÛÙ¾Ø³ÙÙ**

Though something like this is the actual text:
**سلام  سلام لرم ایپسوم**

Testing on Android Phone Xperia z3 plus ( Android 6.0)

Using Android studio : **3.1.2**

Using flutter : **flutter_windows_v0.3.2-beta**

Result showing the text in a text widget:

[image]

Comment: i think it's the log panel problem(because i also have that problem ) , try to display that data in widget and wee the result

Comment: tried that still gives these Ø things except that some characters are a bit different(guess they are not available in my android phone):
https://imgur.com/a/S6BNgxJ

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The web server's `Content-Type` header is `Content-Type: text/html`. Note that isn't including a `charset` suffix. It should be saying `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. The `package:http` client looks for this charset when asked to decode to characters. If it's missing it defaults to LATIN1 (not utf-8).

As you've seen, setting the headers on the Request doesn't help, as it's the Response that does the decoding. Luckily, there's a simple fix. Just decode the bytes to String yourself like this.

```
Future<String> loadFarsi() async {
  final response =
      await http.get("http://mobagym.com/media/mobagym-app-info/farsi.html");
  String body = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
  print(body);
  return body;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be clean, you can write a utility function like `jsonDecodeUtf8` :

**json_util.dart**

```
dynamic jsonDecodeUtf8(List<int> codeUnits,
        {Object reviver(Object key, Object value)}) =>
    json.decode(utf8.decode(codeUnits), reviver: reviver);
```

and use it like:

```
String body = jsonDecodeUtf8(response.bodyBytes);
```