# Flutter : String incorrect encoding - toString in flutter converts " to â

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using the following quote

```
return  await client.get(hostname + "/portfolio/" +email+"/").
    then((response){
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            var body = response.body.toString();
            return body; //The body contains text that has quotes in it
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    });
```

The body has text that has quotes in it. For instance there is something like this

```
you"ll ever find
```

however body variable has this inside it

```
youâll ever find
```

notice the quotes got converted to â. Any idea how I can fix this ?

Comment: That probably means the charcode part of the `content-type` header is missing or doesn't match the content.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I currently have this as the content type `'Content-type': 'application/json'` when making a request

Comment: I don't think `you"ll` is valid JSON. It would have to be `you\"ll`.

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/175 and https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/186 might be related.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks that helped!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Arabic characters With Utf-8 charset Retrived with http.get Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318681/invalid-arabic-characters-with-utf-8-charset-retrived-with-http-get-flutter)