# Arabic letters not showing in Http response body - flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

i am developing an flutter app that consume rest API with Arabic character, the Arabic character not showing well.

The code of http.get request:

```
Future<Null> fetchCustomers() {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    return http.get('http://10.0.3.2:8000/transfers/', headers: {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
      HttpHeaders.acceptCharsetHeader:'utf-8', 
    }).then<Null>((http.Response response) {
      final List<Customer> fetchedCustomerList = [];
      var customerListData = json.decode(response.body);
      print(customerListData);
      print('here');
      final customerData =
          (customerListData as List).map((i) => new Customer.fromJson(i));
      print(customerData);
      print('before');
      if (customerListData == null) {
        _isLoading = false;
        notifyListeners();
        return;
      }
      customerListData.forEach((customerData) {
        final Customer customer = Customer(
          id: customerData['id'],
          name: customerData['name']
          mobile: customerData['mobile'],
          address: customerData['address'],
        );
        fetchedCustomerList.add(customer);
      });
      _customers = fetchedCustomerList;
      print(_customers);
      print("after");
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      _selCustomerId = null;
    }).catchError((error) {
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      return;
    });
  }
```

[The character showing as below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KPIf.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Arabic characters With Utf-8 charset Retrived with http.get Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318681/invalid-arabic-characters-with-utf-8-charset-retrived-with-http-get-flutter)

Answer (score 11):

just add 
   `(json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)))`

instead of    `json.decode(response.body)`

this will decode your json into arabic language

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when device don't have the fonts installed.

Try using Arabic fonts in flutter.

Here is the guideline: [Custom Font Guideline Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your server what charterer set you expect from it by setting the `accept` header like below:

```dart
Future<Map<String, String>> getHeaders() {
  return <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  };
}
```

In the example above I'm telling the server that i will send and accept json in UTF-8 charterer set.

`'Content-Type'` for what I'm sending

`'accept'` for what I expect to receive