# Flutter: how to read Arabic Text from API?

Tags: flutter, api, utf-8

Here's my code: how I fetched data from the internet, using the package of HTTP and creating a model class

```
Future<Iterable<SubCategories>> fetchCategories() async {
  final res = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://___________________'),
  );
  final List<dynamic> responseJson = jsonDecode(res.body)["response"];
  late Iterable<SubCategories> allCategories = responseJson
      .map((subCategoryJson) => SubCategories.fromJson(subCategoryJson));
  return allCategories;
}
```

All is well when Fetching English words, but Arabic words don't appear good
I hope anyone can help me find how to read the Arabic text clearly as I can read the English text.
Also, I tried to fix this issue by adding a Header but no results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arabic letters not showing in Http response body - flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55411801/arabic-letters-not-showing-in-http-response-body-flutter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `jsonDecode(res.body)`, try `jsonDecode(utf8.decode(res.bodyBytes))`

### Edit:

Now I saw more questions already here on SO.

[Arabic letters not showing in Http response body - flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55411801/arabic-letters-not-showing-in-http-response-body-flutter)

[Invalid Arabic characters With Utf-8 charset Retrived with http.get Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318681/invalid-arabic-characters-with-utf-8-charset-retrived-with-http-get-flutter)