# Invalid Arabic/Persian Word appears on the text in flutter

Tags: utf-8, flutter

I'm trying to show the correct Arabic/Persian word coming from the api to my `Text()`. As far as it is english it is coming up fine, but as the language changes it returns something like LATIN1.

[image: Latin1 shows up for the arabic word]

I have followed this question to rectify my problem : [Invalid Arabic characters With Utf-8 charset Retrived with http.get Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318681/invalid-arabic-characters-with-utf-8-charset-retrived-with-http-get-flutter)

I have a string `name` coming from the API. It has a bar name as : `Bar Beirut - بار بيروت`. But in the response, I'm getting the above screenshot.

What I have tried to first encode the string and then decode it, but it not working out.

```
var encoded = utf8.encode(data['name']);
this.name = utf8.decode(encoded);
```

So I'm using `this.name` in my `Text()`, but it shows up english character and for arabic it shows up LATIN1. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

try the following, it is working for me with Arabic characters

```
return http.get(Uri.encodeFull(baseUrl), headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }).then((response) {
      return json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
    });
```