# Some of character is not load correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, flutter-web

Example below loads data in my listview but some of the characters are invalid eg. Å    Ä  I'm trying to use utf8

```
var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);

var jsonData = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
```

when I use utf8, result is correct but I get quotation mark and get error while load data in listTile

```
//I/flutter ( 4629): {"items":[{"name":"xyšć",  //character is OK but get quotation mark
//I/flutter ( 4629): {items: [{name: xyÄÄ,  //wrong character



class Api {
  static Future<dynamic> _get(String url) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
```

Any solution?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318681/invalid-arabic-characters-with-utf-8-charset-retrived-with-http-get-flutter/50319716#50319716

Comment: As an aside, it's not considered good Dart style to create classes (like your `Api`) that just contain static methods. Just make their functions top-level functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your server is likely not specifying the charset with the `content-type`, so the `http` package is defaulting to `Latin-1`.

Combine the two parts you gave above. Decode the bytes to a string with `utf8.decode`, then decode that string as JSON to a map with `json.decode`.

```
  var jsonData = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
```