# Flutter Dart - problems with special characters

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm getting a json with the data and setting up the screen. I have problems with the accents and ç that are unconfigured. How do I make the application understand the characters?

```
    Text('Nome:', style: headings),
Text('${obj.nome}'),
```

in this case, the name is coming out of shape.

For example in json is "Análise", on screen AnÃilise

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368663/flutter-fetched-japanese-character-from-server-decoded-wrong/51370010#51370010 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318681/invalid-arabic-characters-with-utf-8-charset-retrived-with-http-get-flutter/50319716#50319716

Comment: SOLVED! utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
Thank's

Comment: You can use utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes) This would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368663/flutter-fetched-japanese-character-from-server-decoded-wrong/51370010#51370010

Comment: I had the same problem, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969357/flutter-dart-problems-with-special-characters#comment107916648_60969357).
Using utf.decode would help you find the solution of this problem.